# to make tab active in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

In my view page i'm using grid view and list view and i want grid view to be active when the page loads.

The problem i'm facing here, is when the browser loads the page,its not showing any data before clicking the tab menu.

Here is my view page..

```
<li id="grid"  class="<?php if($this->session->userdata('view')==='grid'){?>active<?php }?>"><a href="#shop-grid-tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="Javascript: grid_active('grid')"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></a></li>

<li id="list" class="<?php if($this->session->userdata('view')==='list'){?>active<?php }?>"><a href="#shop-list-tab" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript: grid_active('list')"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></a></li>
<--grid view-->
<div class="tab-pane fade  in <?php if($this->session->userdata('view')==='grid'){?>active<?php }?>" id="shop-grid-tab">
    <div class="row ">
     <?php foreach($mengalery as $row){?>
        <?php $images=json_decode($row->image);{?>
          <a href="#"  target=""><img class="slb" src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $images[0];?>" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; " alt="" /></a>
        <?php}}?>
     </div>
</div>

<--list view-->
<div class="tab-pane fade  in <?php if($this->session->userdata('view')==='list'){?>active<?php }?>" id="shop-list-tab">
    <div class="list-view container3">
     <?php foreach($mengalery as $row){?>
      <?php $images=json_decode($row->image);{?>
        <div class="product_blog_image"> <a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $images[0];?>" alt="" class="slb" style="width: 500px; height: 300px; " /></a> </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you get any error? please change `<?php $images=json_decode($row->image);{?>` into `<?php $images=json_decode($row->image);}?>`

Comment: what tabs you are using?

Comment: pls check if your code enable css class active on tab

Comment: if i give css class active like this <div class="tab-pane fade  in active" id="shop-grid-tab"> the problem im facing is in the list view tab the pagination wont work properly

Comment: in the list view tab if i go for 2nd page the grid will appear because of giving css class active in ngrid view